# Appending one Handlebars template to multiple placeholders

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I have inherited some code from a contractor which uses Handlebars. This is basically one html file and a load of javascript. I should start by saying, I'm not a HTML/Javascript developer. I can muddle through but, thats about it.

Basically, there is a single Handlebars template which creates a simple contact form, and it is dropped into multiple locations using

```
$('.PLACEHOLDER_FAQ-Contact-Form').append( $('#TEMPLATE_FAQ-Contact-Form').html() ).trigger('create');
```

The placeholder appears in 5 locations in the HTML and in each of these the line above inserts the template. The placeholders look like this in the HTML:

```
<span class="PLACEHOLDER_FAQ-Contact-Form"></span>
```

This works fine, but the problem is I need to modify the form so that we can identify which form on the site the user used. I intend to do this by passing a parameter into the template when its written out.

I've never used Handlebars before, so I got this far:

```
var context = {section : ["concept","solution-outline","design","delivery","close"] };
var emailHTML = $('#TEMPLATE_FAQ-Contact-Form').html();
var emailTemplate = Handlebars.compile(emailHTML);
$('.PLACEHOLDER_FAQ-Contact-Form').append( emailTemplate(context) ).trigger('create');
```

and modified the template so that the form ID looks like this:

```
<form id ="{{section}}-Form-FAQ" method ="post" enctype ="text/plain" >
```

The context has an array containing the 5 values i would like to substitute, but currently the result Im getting is

```
<form id="concept,solution-outline,design,delivery,close-Form-FAQ" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
```

I'd like to iterate through the array so that each time a placeholder is found in the HTML it selects one item from the array and then increments the array index so that I get this:

```
<form id="concept-Form-FAQ" method="post" enctype="text/plain">

<form id="solution-outline-Form-FAQ" method="post" enctype="text/plain">

<form id="design-Form-FAQ" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
```

and so on.

Any help would be great, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this (I think it may work :S without testing it):

```
var context = [
    {section : "concept" },
    {section : "solution-outline" },
    {section : "design" },
    {section : "delivery" },
    {section : "close" }
];
//  Set emailHTML
var emailHTML = $('#TEMPLATE_FAQ-Contact-Form').html();
//  Complie Handlebars
var emailTemplate = Handlebars.compile(emailHTML);
//  For each .PLACEHOLDER_FAQ-Contact-Form
$('.PLACEHOLDER_FAQ-Contact-Form').each(function(i){
    //  Append emailTemplate with context[i]
    $(this).append(emailTemplate(context[i])).trigger('create');
});
```

It uses handlebars, but maybe you dont even need handlebars to set the ID.

```
//  Id list
var id = ["concept", "solution-outline", "design", "delivery", "close"]
//  For each .PLACEHOLDER_FAQ-Contact-Form
$('.PLACEHOLDER_FAQ-Contact-Form').each(function(i){
    //  Set emailHTML
    var emailHTML = $('#TEMPLATE_FAQ-Contact-Form').html();
    //  Set emailHTML ID seperatly
    emailHTML.attr('id',id[i])
    //  Append emailHTML
    $(this).append(emailHTML).trigger('create');
});
```

However its not the best for having the correct id attached to the correct .PLACEHOLDER_FAQ-Contact-Form as...

```
$('.PLACEHOLDER_FAQ-Contact-Form').each
```

...will loop through the page and name the top .PLACEHOLDER_FAQ-Contact-Form on the page after the first node in the array and so on (there isn't much control). It would be better to get the .PLACEHOLDER_FAQ-Contact-Form parent ID (or the likes) so you can name it relative to its position (assuming the parents has a useful ID).

Hope that help (and works).

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much. the first solution works perfectly! seems so obvious now its in front of me.